# VS Code DevContainer remote user variable

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

Is it possible to use a variable for "remoteUser" inside .devcontainer.json?
Something like the following:

```json
{
  "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
  "service": "devcontainer",
  "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces/${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}",
  "remoteUser": "${containerEnv:RM_USER}"
}
```

If I use such config, I get a error `unable to find user ${containerEnv: no matching entries in passwd file`